# Animate property inside user control from storyboard in resource

Tags: wpf, user-controls, storyboard

I have a `Resources.xaml` file that contains a [`Storyboard`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.aspx) targeted at a control named `myButton` (this control is in another user control):

```
<ResourceDictionary ...>
  <Storyboard x:Key="expandWizard">
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="myButton"
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                     To="200" Duration="0:0:0.250" />
  </Storyboard>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The resource dictionary is referenced in a `Shell.xaml` file that contains a user control `Test`:

```
<Window xmlns:test="clr-namespace:MyProject.UI" ...>
  <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Resources.xaml" />
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Window.Resources>

  <!-- User control that contains a button. -->
  <test:Test x:Name="testControl" />
</Window>
```

And finally the user control `Test.xaml` contains a button called `myButton`:

```
<UserControl ...>
  <Button x:Name="myButton" Content="OK" />
</UserControl>
```

When I run the story board I receive an error: `InvalidOperationException: 'myButton' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'MyProject.UI.Shell'`.

This makes some sense since `myButton` isn't directly inside `Shell.xaml` but how can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to run the Storyboard directly on the targeted control. Assume your UserControl is named testControl, then you can call

```
Storyboard sb = (Storyboard)Resources["expandWizard"];
testControl.BeginStoryboard(sb);
```

Comment: Aha, I understand, thanks. Suppose I also have a button inside `Shell.xaml` that I would like to manipulate using the same story board. Is that possible at all? Or do I need two story boards: one for the main window and one for the user control?

Comment: Well, if that button inside the main window is named myButton, the storyboard will also work, provided that you call BeginStoryboard on the window object. In fact the storyboard will run anywhere where its TargetName property will resolve to an animatable object with a Width property. See the MSDN for the semantics of TargetName here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.targetname.aspx

Comment: I get it now. A story board is scoped by its owner (the control calling `BeginStoryboard`). So it is impossible to have one story board that animates controls in both a `Window` and a `UserControl`.

Comment: And to reply to your question: the button inside the main window is not named `myButton`. It's another button that I would like to animate using the same storyboard (but it seems this is impossible).